# Change docker container username

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I manually renamed user inside docker container, from that was specified in `Dockerfile`. This container is huge, I don't want to rebuild it, or start another one, how to get it back?
I see old username under 'User' property in docker inspect, and starting this container fails with

> unable to find user cmbuild: no matching entries in passwd file

This is because I renamed it to 'build'
is there any way to change user in docker container config?
and to make it harder, I use **Docker Desktop for Windows** (i.e. moby Linux)

Answer (score 2):

At least, when you do a modification in a live container, you can try and commit it as a new image.

With docker 1.13, the syntax now is [`docker container commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_commit/):

```
docker container commit -p -m "Change user" <container> <name[:tag]>
```

That way, any container started from said new image should keep the modifications done previously.

Answer (score 0):

Every changes you made in Docker, make sure that you have to commit it.

```
docker container commit
```

maybe you need to create an account in docker hub, so you can push every changed images to your dockerhub acc.

Comment: `docker container commit` is what I suggested in my answer.